# Density of $C_c^\infty$ in $W^{1,\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, density-function

Let $p\in[1,\infty)$. We know that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a dense subspace of $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and if $\Omega$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $C^\infty(\Omega) \cap W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

In my notes there is:

> if $p=\infty$ these results don't hold, in fact, 
>   the limit in $W^{1,\infty}$ of a sequence in $C^\infty \cap W^{1,\infty}$ is a $C^1$ function.
>   As counterexample take $u(x)=|x|$ is in $W^{1,\infty}(-1,1) \setminus C^1(-1,1)$.

The question is: is true that the limit in in $W^{1,\infty}$ of a sequence in $C^\infty \cap W^{1,\infty}$ is $C^1$? Does the sequence $\sqrt{x^2+1/n}$ converges at $|x|$ in $W^{1,\infty}(-1,1)$?

Comment: There is probably a typo. It should read "of regular functions in $C^1$".

Comment: @Mirko Just edited, I've removed some ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence
$$
f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1/n}
$$
does not converge to $f(x)=|x|$ in the $W^{1,\infty}-$norm. In fact, $\{f_n\}$  does not converge to any function in the $W^{1,\infty}-$norm, since for every $m\in\mathbb N$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_m-f_n\|_{W^{1,\infty}}
\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_m'-f_n'\|_{L^\infty}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|x|\le 1}|f_m'(x)-f_n'(x)|=1.
$$

Comment: Thanks, Very neat! Now I see: the limit in $W^{1,\infty}$ of a sequence in $C^\infty \cap W^{1,\infty}$ is a $C^1$ function. The proof is a direct application of the fact that continous function are closed under uniform convergence so $f'$ must be continous. So the statement is true.